# Tab consuming in TabPane on default closing

Tags: java, tabs, event-handling, javafx-2, javafx

I have created a program in which a **TabPane** contains multiple **Tabs**.
When someone tries to close any Tab, I want to execute my own code: when a user clicks on the default close button for any Tab, it will ask for confirmation. 
If the user says "Yes" then the tab will be closed, otherwise it will remain open.

How can I do this?

I am doing something like below. but the Tab is still getting closed. How would I consume that Tab?

```
Tab tab = new Tab();
TabPane tabPane=new TabPane();
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

tab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                 t.consume();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting my own way as given below.
I have created a hyperlink and set it as graphic for that Tab and its work fine for me.

```
Hyperlink hlink = new Hyperlink();
Image image = new Image(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/close.png"));
hlink.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
hlink.setFocusTraversable(false);
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.setGraphic(hlink);
hlink.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
              //Do somthing
         }
});
```

Comment: This is cool. But it is adding graphic before tab title. Is it possible to add the graphic after the tab title?

Answer (score 9):

The `Tab` implementation for Java 8 has an `onCloseRequest` property which allows you to prevent tab closing:

```
/* The installed event handler can prevent tab closing 
   by consuming the received event. */
public void setOnCloseRequest(EventHandler<Event> value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution.
If you add your own "prompt the user" logic to the code below, it should do what you want.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538227/tab-consuming-in-tabpane-on-default-closing");
        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 640, 360, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);

        rootPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        rootPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        rootPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Set<Node> nodes = tabPane.lookupAll(".tab-close-button");

        for (final Node node : nodes) {
            node.setUserData(node.getOnMouseReleased());

            node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    boolean removeTab = false; // prompt the user

                    if (removeTab) {
                        ((EventHandler<MouseEvent>) node.getUserData()).handle(arg0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have added 3 tabs in TabPane and giving tabClosingPolicy to "ALL_TABS" . But still
Set<Node> nodes = tabPane.lookupAll(".tab-close-button");
method returns the empty Set.

Comment: It seems that tabPane.lookupAll(".tab-close-button"); only works as expected if you call it after Stage.show().  Are you calling lookupAll() before calling Stage.show()?

Comment: Yes, you are right. but now `node.getOnMouseReleased()` given the null value.

Comment: Perhaps there's still some differences between your code and the sample code above.  When you run the sample code above, were you able to disable/enable tab closing by setting the removeTab boolean to false/true?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same as you have given above. 
`boolean removeTab = false;` 
`if (removeTab) {`
`((EventHandler<MouseEvent>) node.getUserData()).handle(arg0);`
                 `}`
but still tab is getting closed. but I think when `removeTab` value is false, it should not close the tab.

Comment: I am using Java 7 Update 6 on Mac OS X 10.8.2.  What are you using?

Comment: I am using java 1.7.0_09 on Window 7.

Answer (score 1):

Change to `onMousePressed` instead of `setOnMouseReleased`,

And also the close triggers to `onMousePressed` instead of `OnMouseReleased`.