# Confirm dialog window when closing a tab

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX. I want to create `Listener` which calls question dialog when user closes a tab into the `TabPane`. So far I managed to create tabs dynamically and add some custom configuration.

```
    tabAvLabel = new Label(ss);

    tabPane.getTabs().add(0, tab);  // Place the new tab always first
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);    // Always show the new tab
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS); // Add close button to all new tabs
```

I don't know what event listener I need to use and how to define it. Would you show me how to implement this?

Comment: Please see related [Tab consuming in TabPane on default closing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13538227) and search result [confirm dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx-2%5D+%5Bjavafx%5D+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+confirm+dialog).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab consuming in TabPane on default closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538227/tab-consuming-in-tabpane-on-default-closing)

Answer (score 10):

You can try onCloseRequest for Tab class

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<Event>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(Event arg0) 
    {
        //your code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
tabAvLabel = new Label(ss);

tabPane.getTabs().add(0, tab);  // Place the new tab always first
tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);    // Always show the new tab
tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS); // Add close button to all new tabs
tabPane.getOnClosed(), setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>(){
    @Override void handle(Event e){
        // What you have to do here
    }
})
```

For more information, see http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#onClosedProperty

Comment: The OP wants a TAB_ON_CLOSING event, not TAB_ON_CLOSED. And indeed there is `onCloseRequest` event in JavaFX-8.

Comment: So please consider this answer on Oracle Forums : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2327254

Answer (score 0):

I've hacked a similar support you have in jdk8 support into 2.2 (https://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/tree/bundles/runtime/org.eclipse.fx.e4.controls.fx2/src/org/eclipse/fx/e4/controls/fx2)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @VagrantAI can work. But you have to add the following codes on your 'OK' button click action function:

```
stage.fireEvent(
            new WindowEvent(
                    stage,
                    WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST
            )
);
```

While the problem of this approach is the event is triggered when you click 'X' to close the window too. This should not be the purpose normally.

To solve this, add a flag (or static variable) in the class that loads the window. So every time the window is loaded, set the flag to false. When the window is closed, set the flag only when the 'OK' button is clicked. Then you can do your action regarding the value of this flag.